# Sorting in GWT based on String

Tags: java, gwt, sorting

I need to sort a List based on MyDto.name in client-side GWT code.  Currently I am trying to do this...

```
Collections.sort(_myDtos, new Comparator<MyDto>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(MyDto o1, MyDto o2) {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
        }
});
```

Unfortunately the sorting is not what I was expecting as anything in upper-case is before lower-case.  For example  ESP comes before aESP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the bad boy you want: [String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)

Comment: Where do we add this?

Comment: The second argument of Collections.sort

Answer (score 2):

That's because capital letters come before lowercase letters.  It sounds like you want a case insensitive comparison as such:

```
Collections.sort(_myDtos, new Comparator<MyDto>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(MyDto o1, MyDto o2) {
        return o1.getName().toLower().compareTo(o2.getName().toLower());
        }
});
```

toLower() is your friend.

Comment: This would work as well but String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER seems to work best.

Comment: And I might add that it would be better/easier to use `compareToIgnoreCase` http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String), though the results should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I usually go for this one:

```
@Override
public int compare(MyDto o1, MyDto o2) {
    return o1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getName());
}
```

Because it seems to me that whatever String manipulations you otherwise do (toLower() or toUpper()) would turn out to be less efficient. This way, at the very least you're not creating two new Strings.